# Vb6 calculate update

Tags: sql, vb6

How do I calculate and update the refundamt?

I have these three rows initially in database:

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  0 
2   |  200      |  0
3   |  300      |  0
```

If refund is 350, the refundamt will be updated as follow, the refundamt cannot be more then the tranamt:

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  100 
2   |  200      |  200
3   |  300      |  50
```

When refund again with 50, it will only update the last record, the refundamt will be updated as follow:

```
NO  |  TRANAMT  |  REFUNDAMT
1   |  100      |  100 
2   |  200      |  200
3   |  300      |  100
```

Comment: I think you need to give us more information. What code do you have already?

Comment: What I have is select the three rows.

Comment: The convention on stack overflow is to edit the question to make it better in response to a request for more information. Also, if you paste in the code you have (ideally just the relevant context) then people can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm (not considering multithreading and locks):

1. Let RF be the total refund
2. Find the first row where REFUNDAMT < TRANAMT and call it ROW
3. Calculate the difference DIFF for ROW: DIFF = TRANAMT - REFUNDAMT

   - If DIFF >= RF, update REFUNDAMT in ROW to REFUNDAMT+RF and you are done.
   - If DIFF < RF, update REFUNDAMT in ROW to TRANAMT, let RF = RF-DIFF and go to step 2.